# php navigation validation

Tags: php

How to check if the user has entered the page by clicking on the button and not from copy pasting the URL ?

For example, if a user has clicked on Register I want him/her to go to that page only by clicking the Register button and not by copy pasting the link.
Also, is it a good practice to give the page name on the address bar or should I have to hide the page. If I am hiding the page will I be able to do that ?

For example, if localhost/projname/register.php. I don't want people to see the register or login or about or anything on the address bar except localhost/projname.

Comment: Only showing the page on a POST could do that (possibly add a check for a token with a limited lifetime to check whether they come from your form), although I think you might be trying to solve a problem the wrong way if this is your requirement. What is the reason one cannot go straight to the url?

Comment: You can check the HTTP referer, but it's highly unreliable and easily forged/faked/subverted, and in many cases, simply not present.

Comment: @Wirkken: May be I am thinking it can add additional security to the webpage. I am still learning so I would accept comments and suggestions to learn more about PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is to use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` to verify that they clicked a link from your site, but this method isn't fool-proof as many Firewall and Anti-virus suites will remove the Referrer information.

A better method would be to generate a temporary `session` token on the pages of your site, and check for that token when the Register page is opened.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe check if he used $_POST, something like:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
// do ya thing
}
else
{
?>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
are you sure? <input type="submit" value="yes">
</form>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `HTTP_REFERER` data of the [$_SERVER](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) reserved variable to see where did the user come from.

```
if(empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
    // if we are here, the user copy pasted the url.
}
```

As for your second question, you can't totally "hide the page" like you're suggesting. The web server must know which page to show, so the browser must know has well.

You can however obfuscate the page name. For example you can call the page "sfhjgdjkfg" so the user won't be able to know that this is the "registering" page. But I think it's really a bad idea, why in the first place want you to hide this ?

Comment: May be I am thinking that can be some kind of security to the website. I am novice so I just want to know how things work in a real time environment. This is because I am developing a website for a real time use. So I am thinking about all odds and evens that I must follow in developing a website

Answer (score 0):

If your form uses POST parameters, the browser will pass on some POST data. You could then check

```
if (empty($_POST)) {
   //didn't click the button, just went straight to the url
}else{
   //did click the button
}
```

Comment: DON'T USE EMPTY OR ISSET ON $_POST!! That is by far the incorrect way to check if the server requested a $_POST.

Comment: How so? This is how I have always done it. I understand it's possible for a person to send POST data simulating he clicked the form, though

Comment: Yes, it is possible to recreate a dummy form and target the page. But I agree that isset and empty may work, but I'd be more specific by adding the exact index I'm looking for in the index.